# How to get the text after a split when using a function?

Tags: python, proxies

I am trying to split a user:pass:host:port proxy into user:pass and host:port, I know how to get the user:pass using proxytest = proxy.split("@")[0] when the proxy is user:pass@localhost:8080, it returns user:pass but how can I get the localhost:8080? Preferably a very easy way if possible. The proxy is opened in a .txt file and may be changed so I do not know the exact string.

Comment: just use "user:pass@localhost:8080".split("@")[1]  or localPath =proxy.split("@")[1]

Comment: It seems unlikely that you're unable to modify the snippet that you currently have to access the second part. If you don't understand that line well enough to do that, I'd recommend a structured tutorial e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/.

Comment: @toheedNiaz That's splitting a string not what I want

Comment: @jonrsharpe It seems stupid that something so simple like that would be impossible?

Comment: What do you mean that's not what you want? It's what you're doing now! Of course this isn't impossible, indeed it's so trivial that the only charitable assumption is that you haven't correctly explained the problem. I'd recommend you [edit] the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I dont see whats wrong with the question

Comment: I just need to get localhost:8080 when I split user:pass and local:host via the @

Comment: user:pass and localhost:8080 are just examples of what the proxy could be

Comment: Check out urlparse for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) or [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: The answer was really simple my friend helped me
prox = "user:pass@host:port"
userpass = prox[0:prox.find("@")]
hostport = prox[prox.find("@")+1:]

Comment: That's doing what the first comment suggested, which you explicitly said you didn't want, but in a less readable way.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2 you can use the [`urlparse.urlsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) function to accomplish this without any actual parsing.

```
from urlparse import *

x = "http://user:pass@localhost:8080"
parts = urlsplit(x)

print parts.username        #Prints 'user'
print parts.password        #Prints 'pass'
print parts.hostname        #Prints 'localhost'
print parts.port            #Prints '8080'
```

If you were looking for something really naive, you can split on the `@`.

```
x = "user:pass@localhost:8080"
userpass, hostport = x.split('@')
print userpass, hostport    #Prints 'user:pass localhost:8080'
```

Comment: Why would you split it again every time?

Answer (score -1):

The answer was really simple my friend helped me

```
prox = "user:pass@host:port"
userpass = prox[0:prox.find("@")]
hostport = prox[prox.find("@")+1:]
```

Comment: `userpass, hostport = prox.split('@')`